# シェルスクリプトで指定回数ループ処理

Tags: sh

シェルスクリプトで指定回数ループ処理するにはどういった書き方があるでしょうか

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### for / `seq # #`:

```bash
for i in `seq 0 9`
do
  echo "i = $i";
done
```

#### for / C-style ( POSIX 標準外):

```bash
declare -i i
for (( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ))
do
  echo "i = $i";
done
```

```bash
for (( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )) {
  echo "i = $i";
}
```

#### for / {#..#} ( *>= bash-3.0* ):

```bash
for i in {0..9}
do
  echo "i = $i";
done
```

#### while / -lt ~ $(())

```bash
declare -i i=0
while [[ $i -lt 10 ]]
do
  echo "i = $i"
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

---

*Output*:

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
i = 8
i = 9
```

- Bash Reference Manual, [Looping-Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs)

Answer (score 1):

例えばこうとかどうでしょう。 while の場合です。

```
a=0
while [ $a -ne 10 ]
do
　　a=`expr $a + 1`
　　echo "${a}" # 1-10 まで表示されます
done
```

Answer (score 0):

例えばseqコマンドを使うとこうなるかと思います

```
for i in `seq 1000`
do
/* 処理 */
done
```

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じはいかがでしょうか。

```
loop=10;#繰り返し回数
i=0;

while true
do
/* 処理 */;
i=`expr $i + 1`
if `expr $i \>= $loop`
then
break;
fi
done
```